# Unique subfield of order $2$ of $\mathbb{Q(\zeta_{7}})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: group-theory, polynomials, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials, cyclotomic-polynomials

Actualy this subfield is $\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{7})$ since $X^{2}+7$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ and has $i\sqrt{7}$ as root.

My problem here is to show unicity, I tried something using the tower law since
 $[\mathbb{Q(\zeta_{7})},\mathbb{Q}]=6$ but i got nowhere.

Comment: Immediate with FTGT.

Answer (score 1):

Use the fundamental theorem of Galois theory, namely that subfields of a Galois extension correspond to subgroups of the associated Galois group. Then you just have to show that there is a unique subgroup of order $\frac{6}{2} = 3$ in $\textrm{Gal}\left(\mathbb{Q}\left(\zeta_7\right) / \mathbb{Q}\right) = \left(\mathbb{Z}/\left(7\right)\right)^\times$.

For the sake of completeness: see [here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/cyclotomic.pdf) for a proof that this is the right Galois group (note that its order is indeed $6 = \varphi\left(7\right)$) and see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_Galois_theory) for an explicit description of the correspondence.